# call batch file methods as commands

Tags: shell, batch-file

Please find below sample batch file and sh file that contains method that i want to call as commands, once the files are executed in the session :-

test.bat :-

```
goto:eof

::--------------------------------------------------------
::-- Function section starts below here
::--------------------------------------------------------

::-- testa starts here

:testa

echo "This is testa"

goto:eof

::-- testa ends here

::-- testb starts here

:testb

echo "This is testb"

goto:eof

::-- testb ends here
```

test.sh :-

```
function testa(){
    echo "this is testa"
}

function testb(){
    echo "this is testb"
}
```

For sh files, i am able to call the method from command line, but for batch file it is not working and giving below error :-

```
'testa' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Is it possible to acheive same thing with batch file also.

PFA screenshot.[image]

Comment: How are you calling the subroutine? Just `testa` and nothing else?

Comment: You should also have provided the part of the code which is used to 'get to' the section you've included in your question.

Comment: @SomethingDark : yup, i am simply calling testa in the same session. kindly refer screenshot

Comment: You call something using `call` i.e. `call :testa` or `call :testb`

Comment: I've done some Googling, and it seems that when you run a bash script, the methods stay in the environment and you can call them at will. This is not the case in batch. Technically, batch does not have subroutines; they are actually smaller batch scripts embedded in the main script.

Comment: @SomethingDark : Thanks for your efforts. i have to create multiple batch files then for different commands :(.

Comment: There's no reason why you cannot call a single batch file with a label as an input parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As it is the subroutines inside test.bat aren't normally reachable at all from outside. But there is a `feature` some call it a `bug` that allows access from another batch.

```
:: Other.bat
@Echo off
Call :testa any number args
Call :testb 
Goto :eof
:testa this only a stub
:testb 
test.bat %*
```

Provided test.bat is in the same folder or reachable via a folder included in the `Path` the execution of `other.bat` will show:

```
> other.bat
"This is testa"
"This is testb"
```

The function definition you expect aren't available in batch, but in PowerShell.